# Sublime Text: Reference completion across multiple files using LaTeXTools and import

Tags: auto-completion, import, sublime-text, multiple-files, latextools

Consider the following project structure

```
project
| -- part
|    | -- fileWithLabels.tex
|    | -- fileWithRefs.tex
| -- main.tex
```

Is it possible using `Sublime Text 3` and `LaTeXTools` to achieve auto completion using references to labels in a different file that is *not* the main file, if the files are included using `\import` of the [import package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/import)?

You easily find the solution of passing the `main.tex` to every file, like this

```
%!TEX root = ../main.tex
```

This works great, if I simply `\input` the files, but with `\import` only labels in the `main.tex` are offered by the drop-down menu of `LaTeXTools`, but not for example from the `fileWithLabels.tex` while editing the `fileWithRefs.tex`.

Abandoning `import` also seems not to be a good solution, because it is damn useful for nested structures that may be restructured in future (although already the `%!TEX root = ...` breaks this feature).

Comment: The import package is not supported by LaTeXTools (version 3.12.11). You can avoid the tex root comment by using project ans [project settings](https://github.com/SublimeText/LaTeXTools/tree/v3.12.11#multi-file-documents)

Comment: @r-stein: Pity! Do you know whether it is planned in the future? Because import seems to me a very crucial package for large projects. Or is there a good alternative I missed?

Comment: LaTeXTools is moving to a centralized document analysis [#611](https://github.com/SublimeText/LaTeXTools/pull/611) and integrates it into the completion commands [#956](https://github.com/SublimeText/LaTeXTools/pull/956) instead of rewritting the simple document scan in each command. This offers more complex document structure commands as `\import`. Hence it is not directly planned, but will be easy and reasonable to add after that refactoring. Unfortunatly there is currently not a good alternative except [implementing it on your own](https://github.com/SublimeText/LaTeXTools/issues/499).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Support of the import package is now on the plan [#990](https://github.com/SublimeText/LaTeXTools/pull/990) and will most likely be added in the next minor release (`3.13.0`).

Until then I made a branch (`pkgimport_merge`) on [github](https://github.com/r-stein/LaTeXTools/tree/pkgimport_merge), which merges the pull requests to support the import package.
You can download that branch (ensure you have selected that branch) as zip, unpack it, and replace the LaTeXTools package in the SublimeText packages directory. You can access that directory in ST by selecting **Preferences>Browse Packages...** .
If you are familiar with git, you can also directly clone it:

```
git clone https://github.com/r-stein/LaTeXTools.git -b pkgimport_merge
```

If you see an issue please let me know by adding a comment to the pull request.